# Storing Json into MySQL database from Node.js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but after search ferociously, I can not seem to find the answer I am looking for. I have a script in *.js format that creates a json data array then stores it in a json file.

The array setup is:

```
var sessionState = {
    currentWalletNdx: 0,
    genesisBlockId: 0,
    genesisBaseTarget: 0,
    genesisBlockTimestamp: 0,
    current: {
        blockHeight: 0,
        baseTarget: 0,
        startTime: 0,
        totalShare: 0,
        submitters: 0,
        bestDeadline: 0,
        totalPayments: 0,
        netDiff: 0
    },
    prevBlocks: []
};
```

And to store the data in a json file the function is:

```
saveSession: function () {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(sessionState, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('pool-session.json', jsonData);
},
```

My question is, how can I write it in this js file to store the saved json array in a mysql table using the json type so I view the data later using php & mysql?

Comment: I'm thinking you're using nodejs, am I right?

Comment: Yes I am. I know how to make a connection in node js to a mysql db but am unsure as to handle to data and insert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var database = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'host',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database'
});
database.connect(function(connectionError){
  if(connectionError){
    throw connectionError;
  }
  var sql = "INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES ('" + jsonData + "')";
  database.query(sql, function(queryError, queryResult){
    if(queryError){
      throw queryError;
    }
  });
});
```

Change `table` for the name of your table and `column` for the name of the column where you want to insert the JSON. And, of course, the database connection information

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to SQL injection though?

Comment: Yes it is, but I assumed it was something fast to store the numbers and access them in another environment. I could be wrong though, so I upvoted your comment in case someone else comes looking for this