# how to write json dynamic to local json in angular

Tags: json, angular, forms, typescript

i have tried using fs module but I couldn't use this module in my project

```js
const fs = require('fs');
import * as fs from ('fs')
```

None of the above commands don't work

Comment: client side you don't have nodejs (thats where the fs comes from)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) or the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329293/save-json-string-to-client-pc-using-html5-api). You can't use node.js modules on the SPA.

If you want to do that, you need to create an API and save on the server side.

You can in cases use node modules as described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430276/require-node-module-in-angular2-component), but the browser will not allow to access the file system as you intend to do with th fs module.

Comment: Can the project be stored inside for reuse?

Comment: What do you mean? Inside where?

Comment: inside myproject

Comment: Can I recover with this module  data json stored again?

Comment: If you save with an api, then yes, you can retrieve by the api. The save file module still just save in the file system and won't be retrievable by the app

Comment: Is there an example in this case I could not find an example of this in Angular

Comment: i want json dynamically created from formbuilder store and reuse again

Comment: Create an api, save it in a database or a no SQL solution and retrieve

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106905/storing-json-into-mysql-database-from-node-js

Answer (score 0):

fs module is node module and You can't use it on the client-side.
I suggest you use this 
[Save JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329293/save-json-string-to-client-pc-using-html5-api)

Comment: i wanna use in angular help me

Comment: Can the project be stored inside for reuse?

Comment: Did you see the link I posted above?